# Unable to add file to index using eGit plugin (Eclipse Neon3)

Tags: eclipse, git, commit, egit, git-add

Eclipse is showing the below error when I select to add a file to index. Is there any way to fix this?

```
Failed to add resource to index
    Failed to add resource to index
    Exception caught during execution of add command
```

[image: Eclipse error message]

Below is the stack trace of the exception:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Failed to add resource to index
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.AddToIndexOperation.execute(AddToIndexOperation.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.actions.AddToIndexActionHandler$1.run(AddToIndexActionHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: Exception caught during execution of add command
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(AddCommand.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.AddToIndexOperation.execute(AddToIndexOperation.java:77)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.LockFailedException: Cannot lock C:\Users\kkuma203\git\voice-war-nwp-pluto\.git\index
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.lock(DirCache.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.lock(DirCache.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache.lock(DirCache.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.lockDirCache(Repository.java:1192)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.AddCommand.call(AddCommand.java:148)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this error by **manually deleting** `index.lock` file. 
I am now able to add files to index.

The file is located at **`/home/user/location/.git/index.lock`**.